# How to join tables and get the result from the two tables when they appears in the first table and not in the second or vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables that i want want to join in SQL server 2012. The join must be at the column tblA.customer_id to tblB.customer, after joining the 2 table tblA and tblB, i want if the tblA.date_of_revevenue equals tblB.revenue_date, then add the tblA.revenue + tblB.revenue_amount and display them in 1 row, but and if the tblA.date_of_revevenue differs from tblB.revenue_date then display them in 2 different rows in the result table Tbl_Total_Revenue.

I've passed more than 10 hours trying to join using full outer join but it doesn't work.Please i need your help, guys.

This is the sample tables of what i have and what i am looking for is the result table that looks like the one below.
Thank you

## tbl_A

*Customer_id  |  Date_of_revenue    |         Revenue

- C1          |  201201            |                   100
- C2          | 201203                 |  120.20
- C4          |  201304            |          150
- C5          |  201401            |           70

## tbl_B

*Customer   |   Revenue_date  | Revenue_amount

- C1       |    201201       |    50
- C2       |    201203       |    200
- C3       |    201403       |    250
- C5       |    201310       |    50
- C4       |    201401       |    20

Result table I want

## Tbl_Total_Revenue

*Customer_id    | Revenue_date  | Total_revenue

- C1           |      201201   |               150
- C2           | 201203    |               320.20
- C3           | 201403    |               250
- C4           | 201304    |               150
- C4           | 201401    |               20
- C5           | 201401    |               70

Comment: For `customer_id = C5` amd `date_of_revenue = 201401`, the resulting table should have `total_revenue = 140` (i.e. 70 + 70). Right?

Comment: No, i forgot for c5, it have also to appear twice in the result table, because the dates are different

Comment: If you remember it now, why don't you rectify the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in sample data (or expected result), there should be two rows for C5:

```
select isnull(a.Customer_id, b.Customer), isnull(a.Date_of_revenue, b.Revenue_date),
    sum(isnull(a.Revenue,0)+isnull(b.Revenue_amount,0)) as Total_revenue
from tbl_A a
full join tbl_B b on a.Customer_id = b.Customer
and a.Date_of_revenue = b.Revenue_date
group by isnull(a.Customer_id, b.Customer), isnull(a.Date_of_revenue, b.Revenue_date)
order by isnull(a.Customer_id, b.Customer), isnull(a.Date_of_revenue, b.Revenue_date)
```

Comment: Dean, you are wonderful for sure. It works very great and many thanks for your help Buddy. God bless you more and more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Customer_id, Date_of_revenue, SUM(Revenue)
FROM
    (
        (SELECT Customer_id, Date_of_revenue, Revenue FROM tbl_A)
        UNION
        (SELECT Customer Customer_id, Revenue_date Date_of_revenue, Revenue_amount Revenue FROM tbl_B)
    )
GROUP BY Customer_id, Date_of_revenue
```